# How to prevent a program from waiting to receive a message from client?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, networking

I was creating a Chat system where the program will try to receive a message from every online client but the problem is the program is waiting for the first client to send something and receive then it is listening to another.
Please see the code below I simplified the code without providing the main.

```
import socket
port = input("Port: ")
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(5)
a, b = s.accept()
print "Connection", "with", b[0], "Created Successfully"
while True:
    try:
        rec = a.recv(1024)
        print rec
    except:
        print "Time Out"
```

I want the program to check if there is any value in `rec` or not (The client program has sent anything or not), if not it will print `Time Out` without waiting for the client to send anything.

Comment: You want to use the [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) system call.

Comment: What you are currently doing is called a blocking call to receive the bytes, what you wanna do is a non blocking call to receive the data (and pass a callback to make updates) so that your main thread does not freeze.

Answer (score 1):

Visit https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket-objects
This is for socket python2.7

socket.setblocking(flag)
Set blocking or non-blocking mode of the socket: if flag is 0, the socket is set to non-blocking, else to blocking mode. Initially all sockets are in blocking mode. In non-blocking mode, if a recv() call doesn’t find any data, or if a send() call can’t immediately dispose of the data, an error exception is raised; in blocking mode, the calls block until they can proceed. s.setblocking(0) is equivalent to s.settimeout(0.0); s.setblocking(1) is equivalent to s.settimeout(None).

socket.settimeout(value)
Set a timeout on blocking socket operations. The value argument can be a nonnegative float expressing seconds, or None. If a float is given, subsequent socket operations will raise a timeout exception if the timeout period value has elapsed before the operation has completed. Setting a timeout of None disables timeouts on socket operations. s.settimeout(0.0) is equivalent to s.setblocking(0); s.settimeout(None) is equivalent to s.setblocking(1).

Answer (score 1):

Multi-thread programming: You need to run your listening function by a thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options in Python.  Just to name two, https://twistedmatrix.com/ and https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Answer (score -1):

Your question is operating system specific.

Use the [select & poll - Waiting for I/O completion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) operations. And probably the [selectors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#module-selectors) module. Or find some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) module.

You may want to read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) to understand how to use Linux [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html); read about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html))

You could read [*Operating System: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand more about OSes.